# Bash script to Import Multiple Databses using Loop

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a folder with many DB.sql.gz files, i want to import them all into a new installation of MySQL Server in one go.

I thought using bash script would be a good idea.

So Far, I have this file as an executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
for filename in *.gz; 
do
tempfile="${z##*/}";
database_name = "${tempfile%.*}";
echo database_name;
mysql -pPASS -u USER;
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
unzip z | mysql -pPASS -uUSER database_name;
done
```

Whats going wrong is that when taking the 'filename' in the for loop, i cant string
manipulate to to remove the extension, I want to do this because the database files are named as the database. ( just want to remove the .sql.gz to get the db name )

Help appreciated

Comment: Where do you set `$z`? Should that be `${filename##*/}`?

Comment: You can't have spaces around `=` in shell.

Comment: unzip is for zip files, not gz files. Use `gunzip`

Comment: To execute a query direectly using `mysql, use `mysql -e 'query'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
for filename in *.gz; 
do
    tempfile="${filename##*/}"
    database_name="${tempfile%%.*}"
    echo $database_name
    mysql -pPASS -u USER -e "CREATE DATABASE $database_name"
    gzcat $filename | mysql -pPASS -uUSER $database_name
done
```

1. `$z` should be `$filename`.
2. No spaces around `=` in assignments
3. You were missing `$` before many variable uses.
4. To execute the `CREATE DATABASE` command, use the `-e` option to `mysql`
5. Use `gzcat` to expand a `.gz` file to stdout.
6. `${tempfile%.*}` should be `${tempfile%%.*}`. `%` removes the shortest match of the pattern, `%%` removes the longest match. This will remove all the suffixes.

Comment: Brilliant: there's just one small blip. Unknown database 'xdb.sql' the string needs not to have the .sql part

Comment: It should be `%%.*`, not `%.*`, so you remove all the suffixes, not just the last one.

Comment: Nearly there, it's not creating the Databases, it's creating one called 'database_name' and failing :(

Comment: That's another place where you were missing `$`. Note also that I changed to double quotes there, since variables aren't expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: Perfect !  I changed the gzcat to gunzip using --stdout and that got over the gzcat issue i had, but thats the winner !